# autostart a program with x seconds delay in lattepanda linux

Tags: linux, autostart

Hi2,

Does anyone knows how to start a program(*made with QT*) automatically but with **x seconds** delay in Linux lattepanda? 
I am using Gnome linux environment.

I am able to start a program without delay by modifying this script:

**sudo gedit /etc/rc.local** 
Before **exit 0**, 
I add **/opt/lampp/lampp start**

*This example is to autostart XAMPP*

--- edit ---

Since i cannot put attachment on the comment, I modified my question with screenshot picture according to @arkascha
[image]




[image]

Comment: Linux is a multi user evironment. That means you can not simply start applications relying on a desktop environment depending on the run level (so for example right after booting up). You have to wait for a user login and for the users desktop to become available. So typically you want to add graphical programs to the users autostart folder or into his profile files (e.g. `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`). The delay can be achieved by a simple wrapper script implementing a `sleep` call, or by simply concatenating both calls (e.g. `sleep 5; program`).

Comment: hi @arkascha , thank you for replying. currently the User will be login automatically when the system start. 
And where is ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile located ?

Comment: Sure, an auto login is possible, but what I wrote still applies, only that the desktop environment gets started automatically. In unixoid systems the `~` is expanded to the users "home" folder, typically something like `/home/<username>`, though that can be configured. So you are looking for those files in the users home folder. You want to read about those files...

Comment: thank you for staying with me @arkascha. ^_^
I am not sure if i did it the right way., but it doesn't work.
<br>I have attached a screenshot by modfying my answer. Could you please take a look what i did wrong. ?

Comment: You do not want to open a desktop session for the root user. No, you don't.

Comment: The actual issue you stumble over: you try to launch a graphical application from a shell that does not have access to a desktop environment. It is more efficient to use a command line editor for such tasks: `joe`, `vi`, `emacs`

Comment: If it doesnt take much of your time,
Could you please kindly attached "step-by-step" screenshot in the Answer section ?  ^_^ v

Comment: I do not have enough information to provide such a guided tour, I do not know your system. You want to edit the file `/home/admin/.bash_profile` or similar, depending on your setup. No need for `sudo` here...